# Installing packages in django project

Tags: python, django, installation

I'm new to django and i tried to install django-widget-tweaks but my app cannot recognize the filter like add_class. I installed widget-tweaks with pip install, then I added it to INSTALL_APPS = [], but nothing work.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Did you import the `add_class` filter from the package?

Comment: Be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this application, but I think it's a Template BACKEND from what it looks like.

first look into settings.py for TEMPLATES then you have to add this package as a BACKEND To it like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND' : 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    }
]
```

Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates) out might help ya.

and also this is not the only step of using it...
you must use views and then import the module like:
`from package.module import attr` (one of the package modules)

then use it and render your templates like it said in the [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks).